# Discarding modified hunk at current position

Tags: magit, vc

I'd like to discard modified hunks (and ideally, view the diff before) basing on the current buffer position.

I have diff-hl so that it's quite obvious which part of a buffer are modified. Now, how to view the diff for the current hunk and/or discard it?

One way I though this might work is some way to jump to magit's view, moving to the selected hunk - this would show the diff, and then `k` would discard it. I was also looking at `vc-mode`, but didn't find anything that would fit that use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- diff-hl: `diff-hl-revert-hunk`
- git-gutter: `git-gutter:revert-hunk`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```el
(defun vc-diff-current-hunk ()
  "Find the hunk at point in a `vc-diff' buffer and narrow it there."
  (interactive)
  (let ((line (line-number-at-pos))
        found)
    (vc-diff)
    (widen)
    (goto-char 1)
    (while (and (not found)
                (re-search-forward
                 "^@@ -[0-9]+,[0-9]+ \\+\\([0-9]+\\),\\([0-9]+\\) @@" nil t))
      (let ((hunk-line (string-to-number (match-string 1)))
            (hunk-count (string-to-number (match-string 2))))
        (setq found (and (>= line hunk-line)
                         (< line (+ hunk-line hunk-count))))))
    (when found
      (save-excursion
        (narrow-to-region
         (point)
         (progn
           (if (ignore-errors (diff-hunk-next) t)
               (point)
             (point-max)))))
      (message "Hunk found"))
    (unless found
      (error "Hunk not found"))))
```